# How to fine tunin the yamnet model and its hyperparameters?

Tags: audio, deep-learning, hyperparameters

Using the steps in the following link, I was able to fine tune the yamnet model https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8425

But I have problem with tuning the hyperparameters of the yamnet model.
If I understand it correctly, each audio is divided into frames with a length of patch_window_seconds and a hop length of patch_window_seconds. The input of the model is a batch of these frames. What if there is a frame of silence in each audio and we label that as our object of interest. Is not that problematic?
Of course, we can change the patch_window_seconds and patch_hop_seconds parameters in the parameter file, but how can we be sure that each frame ends up containing the audio of the object of interest?

I have achieved good accuracy in the training and validation set. I have three sets of tests. For one set, which is from the same distribution as the training data set, the accuracy is good, but for the others, it is not. The test sets I used are from another paper where good accuracy was achieved with a simple CNN for all test sets.